# incorrect syntax error near 'IN' keyword

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How can I use this mysql query in sql server?

If I used same syntax in sql server then I am getting the below error.

> incorrect syntax error near 'IN' keyword

```
select count(1) as total_record 
from sms_allocation 
left join sms_api_definition on sms_allocation.sms_api_definition_id = sms_api_definition.sms_api_definition_id 
where if(('1' = 1 || '4,26,28,31,32,33,37,41,53,56,58,62,63,66,71,72,73,75,76,77,81' = 81 || '4,26,28,31,32,33,37,41,53,56,58,62,63,66,71,72,73,75,76,77,81' = 82), 
      if('0'!='0',reseller_id in (
        select reseller_id 
        from sms_allocation 
        where reseller_id in (0)),reseller_id in (
          select reseller_id 
          from sms_allocation)
        ), reseller_id in (
          select reseller_id 
          from sms_allocation 
          where reseller_id in (0)) and sms_allocate_to='Company');
```

Comment: i am migrate mysql code to MS sql

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the mysql `if` statement with standard sql `case` statement should solve your problem.

```
    select
        count(1) as total_record
    from
        sms_allocation left join sms_api_definition on sms_allocation.sms_api_definition_id = sms_api_definition.sms_api_definition_id
    where
        case when 
            '1' = 1 or '4,26,28,31,32,33,37,41,53,56,58,62,63,66,71,72,73,75,76,77,81' = 81 or '4,26,28,31,32,33,37,41,53,56,58,62,63,66,71,72,73,75,76,77,81' = 82
        then
            case when 
                '0' != '0'
            then
                reseller_id in (
                    select
                        reseller_id
                    from
                        sms_allocation
                    where
                        reseller_id in (0)
                 )
             else
                 reseller_id in (
                     select
                         reseller_id
                     from
                         sms_allocation
                 )
             end
       else    
           reseller_id in (
               select
                   reseller_id
               from
                   sms_allocation
               where
                   reseller_id in (0)
       end
       and 
          sms_allocate_to = 'Company'
);
```

Update: replaced `||` with `or`, sorry I missed that.

Comment: I got below errors:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.

Comment: Updated the answer, please give it a try.